# Float right only works after window resize

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-float, window-resize

It's just incomprehensible! I have a div in the right side (DIV1) and another div next to it on the left (DIV2) and I want to put some elements in DIV2 aligned right.
Here's the image :
[image: Floating problem]

Here's the HTML :

```
<section id='main-container'>
    <aside id='main-side'>

    </aside>
    <nav id='main-nav'>
        hello
    </nav>
    <section id='main-content'>

    </section>
</section>
```

And the CSS :

```
#main-side {
    width:250px;
    min-height:450px;
    border:1px solid silver;
    float:right;
}
#main-nav {
    width:770px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:right;
    border:1px solid silver;
    margin-right:251px;
}
```

The problem as you see in the image is that when I open the page or reload the page the content of DIV2 doesn't go to the right but when I resize the window it goes to the right as I expect. By the way the browser is Chrome and the problem is not in Firefox.
Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: Is there something else in your CSS causing the styles to be overwritten? Testing what you've pasted in my browser it works just fine.

Comment: Here I uploaded the files and css you can view sources : http://brandmap.ir/files/issue/

Comment: Got it, looking now.

Comment: Try removing `width: 770px;` from your `#main-nav` real quick.

Comment: you're welcome, I posted as an answer as well so others who it's solved if they don't read the comments here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was testing it from your site, I was getting the same issue.  By removing `width: 770px;` from your `#main-nav` section, I was able to get it working properly.